# Problems with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I have field called filter1 on a form, I would like to be able to save quoted text into mysql. So I would like to be able to save the value "foo bar"...instead its saving just /

Here is what I have:

```
$keyword1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filter1']);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Here is how I construct the query

```
$keyword1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['filter1']);
$keyword2 = $_POST['filter2'];//."|".$_POST['filterby'];
$keyword3 = $_POST['filter3'];//."|".$_POST['filterby2'];

$urlfilter1 = $_POST['url1'];
$urlfilter2 = $_POST['url2'];//."|".$_POST['url_filter'];
$urlfilter3 = $_POST['url3'];//."|".$_POST['url_filter2'];
//echo "combo_id:".$num." <BR></br>";
//echo "status:".$status." <BR></br>";
//echo "saveQuery:".$saveQuery." <BR></br>";
//$myFilter = "save"; 
$insert_query = sprintf("UPDATE COMBINATION 
                        SET STATUS_ID=%s, QUERY=\"%s\", 
                        KEYWORD1=\"%s\", KEYWORD2=\"%s\", KEYWORD3=\"%s\", 
                        URLFILTER1=\"%s\", URLFILTER2=\"%s\", URLFILTER3=\"%s\" 
                        WHERE COMBINATION_ID=%s",$status,$saveQuery,
                        $keyword1,$keyword2,$keyword3,
                        $urlfilter1,$urlfilter2,$urlfilter3,
                        $num);
//echo "insert_query:".$insert_query." <BR></br>";
$result = mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());
if($result)
{
    echo "Saved successfully<br>";
}
```

} 
?>

Comment: What do you do with $keyword1 after this?

Comment: And how do you construct your SQL statement?

Comment: The problem is not `mysql_real_escape_string` but how you construct the SQL query.

Comment: This is how I construct the query

Comment: ...You do realize you're about 90% of the way to using prepared statements and solving your SQL problems altogether, right?  A `new PDO` here, a `$db->prepare` there, a `s/(\\")?%s(\\")?/?/g` over there, and done.  I swear, i don't get it...

Answer (score 10):

Unless you have a very old and restricted environment, [use PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496). It will save you buckets of sweat and tears. [With PDO it is very easy to escape input and avoid SQL injection attacks, which is illustrated in the answer that this link leads to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).

Comment: There's a link to how to do it. I don't think repeating that answer serves any purpose.

Comment: +1 for being one of the few people to mention PDO around here.

Comment: There was a comment complaining about my answer not earning its keep, but it looks like it has been removed (which makes the second comment seem out of place). I've added another sentence to make it more clear that there is an example on how to use PDO if you follow the link.

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to connect to the database with `mysql_connect()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Then you need to call your INSERT query with `mysql_query()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

By the way, you are doing the right thing by escaping the string before putting it into a query, well done :)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are escaping only one variable, while adding to the query several of them.
Why don't you escape them all?

However, your problem may be somewhere else. 
What is $saveQuery I am curious?